# Reassigning to Python pandas series: garbage collection

Tags: python, garbage-collection, pandas, out-of-memory

I am using a for loop that loads tsv files of about 1gb each into a pandas series. They are always assigned to the same variable and then I use Series.add() to add them to a series that contains the total of the numbers in the series.

Update: To clarify, all the tsv have more or or less the same index, so the length of the total series does not really change only the values get added up.

I would expect the the memory the "old" series to get freed occasionally so that the memory usage stays within bounds. However, the memory usage grows until the 62GB memory of the machine are exhausted.

Has anyone any ideas how to solve the problem? I tried deleting the variable explicitly within the loop and I tried to call gc.collect() in the loop. Both didn't help. I am using Python 2.73.

More details:

In the tsv files first two columns are an index (chromosome and position) and the third column are integer.

the code is:

```
total = pd.read_csv(coverage_file1,sep='\t',index_col=[0,1],header=None,names=  ['depth'],squeeze=True)

for file in coverage_files:
    series = pd.read_csv(file,sep='\t',index_col=[0,1],header=None,names=['depth'],squeeze=True)
    total = total.add(series,fill_value=0).astype(int)
    del series # I tried with and without this and the next line
    gc.collect() 


total.to_csv(args.out,sep='\t',header=None)
```

Comment: it's possible that their is a bug in using squeeze; try without it (and just subset to the get the series); if it IS different pls file a bug report on github

Comment: @Jeff, no the same problem occurs without squeeze

Answer (score 0):

But you still accumulating data in `total`, while `series`being garbage collected. Maybe optimize algorithm? It looks to me you just want to join files of the same format, if it so there is no need to use pandas for this.

Comment: Hi. No, I am not really accumulating the data in total. I am not joining the files but calculating the sum of the series objects. total always stays a series of more or less same length, only the values grow, but not excessively.

Comment: What version of pandas do you use? I've checked your script at my system and had no problem with memory consumption (python2+pandas 0.13.0). Also did you checked how many runs for loop did? May be there is not enough memory to load even 1 series as it can have some overhead for storing data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions rsk. I am using pandas 0.12.0. I have 62Gb  available and each file is 1GB. The for loop is at least doing several runs. I tried with only 5 files and it works, but with 160 files (as i need) it crashes.

Comment: run a gc.collect() - I'd say you're not doing a generation 2 collection.